# Delete Alexa History

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is there any way to access alexa history for a particular app form within that app(or lambda) programatically? 
For e.g If I have library app and want to ensure alexa identifies my request history and tells me which book I already ordered/read etc

Thanks
Rrrrr Arrrr

Answer (score 0):

Alexa will not provide any kind logging history to custom skill, please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887220/log-the-utterenances-that-are-not-handled-by-amazon-alexa/41961676#41961676)